# select the employees in dept D to H who have rate values different from department S

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause, multiple-conditions

```
select *
from emps
where dept in 
    (select dept 
    from emps 
    where dept between "D" and "S"),
(select rate
 from emps
 where dept <> "S")
 order by dept desc;
```

Comment: Post a data sample along with desired output (as text)

Comment: Do not imagine new SQL syntax, use existing one. Comma is not allowed in WHERE clause for expressions combining, use according logical operators..